# Handle an event and non-event function in the same way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events, onclick

I want to have a function that takes a path and navigates to it.  I'd like it to be universally usable.  Like this:

```
export const navigate = (path: string) => {
 getHistory().push(path)
}
```

So, I want to be able to call it as a normal function

`navigate('gohere')`

as well as in response to an onClick action

`onClick={navigate('gohere')`

Unfortunately, that second one doesn't work.  If I add the event in like this:

```
export const clicknavigate = (path: string) => (event: any) => {
    getHistory().push(path)
}
```

then it works, but that means I have to have two functions for every action - one if it is called from a click or mouse event, and one if not.

There has to be a way to handle both with a single function?

Comment: You can create a new function with `bind`, something like `onClick={navigate.bind(this, 'gohere')}` so the `event` object will be passed as the second parameter instead of being first.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
export const clicknavigate = (path: string, event: any) => {
    if(event){
      getHistory().push(path)
    }
    return         
}
```

then call it on your onClick method as follow `onClick={(e) => clicknavigate('gohere', e)}`